# NSCombobox, NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nscombobox

I have the code for timer with time interval 5 seconds. Is there an easy way to control the time interval with NSCombobox or something similar? Let's say: I would like to choose the timer interval from 1 to 5 seconds in the Combo Box.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateTextFieldWithRandomNumber)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `doubleValue` from any [`NSControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[myComboBox doubleValue]
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateTextFieldWithRandomNumber)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```